# How to include different level PHP file in a view in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm working on a CodeIgniter project, and using Linux shared hosting.

```
-- controllers
-- views
  -- common_include
     -- common_header.php
     -- common_footer.php
  -- admin
     -- dashboard.php
  -- front
     -- index.php
```

I'm calling a common PHP file in one of the view pages. I tried the below code in admin/dashboard.php.

```
include_once VIEWPATH . 'common_include\common_header.php';
```

In localhost it's working fine, but when I uploaded it in hosting server it's showing this error:

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: include_once(/home/testuser/public_html/testpro.toours.com/application/views/common_include\mobile_header.php):   
 failed to open stream: No such file or directory
Filename: admin/dashboard.php
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh.. I got the solution.. It's very simple.

instead of backslash i had to use slash

```
include_once VIEWPATH . 'common_include/common_header.php';
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `/` instead of `\` for the line `include_once VIEWPATH . 'common_include\common_header.php';` and the problem will be solved.